# valid xhtml meta tags for facebook open-graph and twitter cards

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, xhtml, meta-tags, xhtml-1.0-strict

to make valid:

- xhtml
- twitter cards
- facebook-graph-api

for http://www.theyact.com/acting-classes/los-angeles/

I've managed to get my code to come up valid everywhere... 
save 1 error on 
http://validator.w3.org/

> there is no attribute "property"

but only 1 instance among the many in the code, only the below seems to ruffle the validator's feathers:

<meta name="og:description" property="og:description" content="...

I'd like the code to be completely valid in validator.w3.org's eyes. What am I missing?

Comment: Does it _need_ to be XHTML? If so, why aren't you serving the page with a real XHTML MIME type?

Comment: Good question. I should probably look into fixing the mime-type the server is serving. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove this element, the validator will complain about the next one containing the `property` attribute.

The `property` attribute is part of RDFa, but your DOCTYPE doesn’t allow the use of RDFa.

If you want to keep using XHTML 1.1, you could change it to:

- [for RDFa 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-rdfa-syntax-20081014/#a_DTD_driver): `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">`
- [for RDFa 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-xhtml-rdfa-20130822/#xhtml-rdfa-driver-module): `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-2.dtd">`

Or simply switch to [(X)HTML5, which comes with RDFa 1.1 support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21559415/1591669).

Comment: Thank you so much, makes sense the doctype was the culprit. Much appreciated.