# Website W3C validator shows "Mismatch between Public and System identifiers in the DOCTYPE declaration", what to do?

Tags: xhtml, doctype, w3c-validation, rdfa

I'm trying to validate my website [Hybrid.cz](http://www.hybrid.cz) in the W3C validator. Unfortunately, it keeps showing the same errors because of the "Mismatch between Public and System identifiers in the DOCTYPE declaration". It says:

> This document uses an inconsistent DOCTYPE declaration. The System
>   Identifier w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd declares the
>   XHTML 1.0 Transitional document type, but the associated Public
>   Identifier -//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0 Transitional//EN does not match
>   this document type.
>
> The recommended Public Identifier for
>   w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd is -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
>   Transitional//EN.

My DOCTYPE is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
```

I'm not really experienced in DOCTYPES. But I want to be able to use RDFa attributes within the site. What should I do?

Comment: Note that [you could also switch to XHTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19974898/1591669), which [allows RDFa by default](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21559415/1591669).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find a DTD which supports the mixture of XML languages you want to use, then you look up the correct Doctype for it.

[Searching](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=XHTML%2BRDFa+1.0&oq=XHTML%2BRDFa+1.0&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.218j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) turns up the [XHTML+RDFa 1.1 - Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa/) specification.

This shows the Doctype to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.1//EN"
                         "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-2.dtd">
```