# Microdata in XHTML 1.1: there is no attribute "itemprop"

Tags: w3c-validation, microdata, xhtml-1.1

I added Microdata to the product pages of my site. That leads to some errors. One of these errors is the following:

> there is no attribute "itemprop"

The error is related to this source code line:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
```

My Doctype is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

How would it be possible to make the page W3C compliant when keeping the same Doctype?

Answer (score 1):

**Microdata** can only be used in (X)HTML5.

If you want to use the Schema.org vocabulary in XHTML 1.1, you could use **RDFa**, but this would [require changing the DOCTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974898/1591669) to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.1//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-2.dtd">
```

(See my answer about [differences between Microdata and RDFa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669).)