# Microdata test: Google, Yandex or neither

Tags: html, microdata

I have tested the microdata code for my website and get 2 different error messages in Google and Yandex testing tools.

1. Google tells me that the Branchof property is empty + I need to add the organization logo.
2. Yandex does not highlights these errors. It tells me to add the address + phone number for the branch.

Should I take these comments into account or should I ignore them?

I definitely want to meet Google's requirements. Can you please help me resolve the error in the code below:

**Home page code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">

<p>
<a itemprop="url" href="URL OF ORGANIZATION WEB PAGE" >
<img itemprop="logo" src="IMAGE NAME OF ORGANIZATION.gif"  /></a>
<meta itemprop="name" content="NAME OF ORGANIZATION" />
</p>
<meta itemprop="description" content="SHORT DESCRIPTION OF ORGANIZATION" >              

</body>
</html>
```

**Product Page code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body itemprop="branchOf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" id="schema-organization"  >

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TravelAgency" itemref="schema-organization" >
<link itemprop="url" href="URL OF HOME PAGE OF BRANCH SITE" />
<meta itemprop="name" content="BRANCH NAME" />                
<img src="http://www.IMAGE OF PAGE.jpg" itemprop="image" />        
</div>

<p itemprop="name" >NAME OF PAGE</p>
<p itemprop="description" >SHORT DESCRIPTION OF PAGE</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535779/using-itemprop-branchof-from-schema-org-microdata-to-refer-to-localbusinesss), it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Microdata, you [have to use (X)HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27509699/1591669). If you want to keep using XHTML 1.0, you could use [RDFa instead of Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669).

About the warnings/errors:

- > Google tells me that […] I need to add the organization logo.

  Google reports that you need to add the properties `url` and `logo` although you have added them (in the first example). This is because of your example values: `IMAGE NAME OF ORGANIZATION.gif` and `URL OF ORGANIZATION WEB PAGE` are not valid URLs, because the spaces have to be percent-encoded (`%20`).

  Your second example misses `logo`. You don’t *have* to add it, it’s just that Google would like to see it, e.g., for showing a Rich Snippet.
- > Google tells me that the Branchof property is empty

  I can’t reproduce this with [Google’s (new) testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/).

  The item is not empty, as you specify `name` and `description`.
- > Yandex […] tells me to add the address + phone number for the branch.

  This just means that they would like to see the additional information, e.g. for showing an enhanced search results.

Comment: Thanks Unor! Always to the rescue! :-) The names of the URL and images do not have spaces in teh actual code. Now I understand that what Google and Yandex show as errors means that they can still read the information but they just want more details to create a rich snippet.