# How to use RDFa "vocab" within XHTML

Tags: xhtml, rdfa

I'm trying to get this (simple) webpage done for my assignment and it needs to pass through http://validator.w3.org/
It also needs to use RDFa. However no matter what I do, the RDFa `vocab` never gets passed by the validator.

Here's what I got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd'>

<body vocab="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The `vocab` attribute is defined in RDFa 1.1, but with your current DOCTYPE, you are using RDFa 1.0.

Your options:

- Keep using XHTML 1.1 and RDFa 1.0, and use the `xmlns:…` attribute(s) instead of the invalid `vocab` attribute:

  ```
  <body xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
  ```

  (Then you have to use the prefix `foaf:`.)
- Keep using XHTML 1.1, but [switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974898/1591669) to a DOCTYPE that supports RDFa 1.1:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-2.dtd">
  ```
- Switch to XHTML5, which supports RDFa 1.1 by default:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  ```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Do you really have to use XHTML? I would recommend to use an HTML5 doctype. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-rdfa/ has some examples.

Also, make sure you use the NU validator from W3C: https://validator.w3.org/nu/ - the one you are using is old and should no longer be used.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!