# Using an individual tag without breaking the standards?

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c-validation

I would like to create some kind of API where people can include a hidden information inside a website, so that a bot can read the information.

I know it is possible with meta-tags, but I am considering using some kind of individual tag, because then I can use DOM which is a bit more comfortable to work with, and it is easier to read by humans.

Example:

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
<mytag id="123" foo="bar" bar="foo"></mytag>
...
<mytag id="345" foo="bar" bar="foo"></mytag>
...
</body>
</html>
```

My question is, if it is possible to make this individual tag somehow conform to the standards, maybe by creating some kind of DTD ?

I would like to support HTML 4.01, XHTML and HTML 5, if possible.

Comment: I will look at this question, however, my question goes in a different direction, as I am searching a possibility to support HTML 4 and XHTML too. So, a HTML5-only solution is not what I am looking for.

Comment: There are many different answers, depending on who you ask. _Technically_, the answer is no, the tag name `mytag` breaks the standards.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly that can't be done with a div with a specific class, data blocks in JavaScript sections in the file, or by using a non-HTML xml file?

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I would like that people can output some visual information along with invisible machine readable information. So a pure XML file is not a solution. Javascript data blocks are a bit tricky because I would like to read the machine readable part with PHP, so I would need a JS parser. A span or div with data attributes might be a solution, although not 100% HTML 4. (Can I add some kind of DTD at the head of the HTML4 document to let it know that the data tags are valid?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to support HTML 4.01 *and* HTML5 makes this hard. You can’t use **`meta`-`name`** elements ([would work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669) for HTML 4.01, but they have to be registered for HTML5), you can’t use custom **`data-*`** attributes (not allowed in HTML 4.01), you can’t use **Microdata** ([only defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22284698/1591669) for HTML5+), you can’t use **custom elements** ([only defined](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements) for HTML5+).

I can think of two ways.

#### `script` element as data block

In HTML5, the `script` element [can also be used for data blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16115085/1591669). Examples: [`text/html`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428316/1591669), [`text/plain`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19298638/1591669).

The HTML 4.01 spec [doesn’t define it like that](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html401-20180327/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1), but it should still be possible/valid (it’ll understand it as "script", but user agents are not expected to try to run it if they don’t recognize the content type as possible for scripts).

Drawback: The content is not part of the document’s DOM.

#### RDFa

It’s [allowed in](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-rdfa-20150317/#additional-rules) HTML 4.01 and HTML5 (you might have to adapt the DOCTYPE for the older HTML versions, [e.g., for XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974898/1591669)).

You can’t use custom elements, but you can add `property` and `content` attributes (for name-value pairs), and you could use `typeof` for "items" (e.g., what you would use the element name for), and you can make use of `meta` and `link` elements (visually hidden by default) in the `body`.

```html
<div vocab="https://api.example.com/voc#" class="the-hidden-information">

  <div typeof="Item-123">
    <meta property="foo1" content="bar1" />
    <meta property="foo2" content="bar2" />
  </div>

  <div typeof="Item-345">
    <meta property="foo1" content="bar1" />
    <link property="foo5" href="/some-url" />
  </div>

</div>
```

(when using RDFa 1.0 instead of 1.1, you’d have to use [`xmlns` instead of `vocab`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31474354/1591669))

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the two suggestions! RDFa sounds very interesting, but it also looks a bit complex (and usually requires a framework for reading them). I think I will go with a JSON data block. This way, I can easily read and write a hierarchical machine readable data structure into the file (I'll locate the `<script type="application/json">` element with PHP's DOM library, and then evaluate its contents with `json_decode`)